# How to make a post request without curl?

Tags: php, http

Considering I don't want to use curl, which is a valid alternative to make a post request?  Maybe `Zend_http_client`?

I just need the basic stuff (I need to request an url with only one post param)

Comment: You would rather deploy framework than use cURL?

Comment: @webarto: deploy? Zend framework only needs one include path. And with that you can access so many feautures that is worth it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using the Zend Framework already you should try the [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) you mentioned:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($host, array(
            'maxredirects' => 3,
            'timeout'      => 30));
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
// You might need to set some headers here
$client->setParameterPost('key', 'value');
$response = $client->request();
```

Comment: no i am not using zend framework, but considering this I should start now :D

Comment: might want to check, but Zend could just be wrapping curl

Comment: Anyway If i want just to use zend_http_client in my framework, is there an installation tutorial for this? Or to use zend_http_client I must use all the framework?

Comment: Ok, it was pretty easy, set include path and go

Answer (score 43):

You could use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)().

The PHP manual has a nice [example here](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). This is just copy past from the manual:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
$context_options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data
            )
        );
?>


$context = stream_context_create($context_options); 
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.php.net', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it yourself via sockets:

```
    $url = parse_url(''); // url
    $requestArray = array('var' => 'value');
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_connect($sock, $url['host'], ((isset($url['port'])) ? $url['port'] : 80));
    if (!$sock) {
        throw new Exception('Connection could not be established');
    }

    $request = '';
    if (!empty($requestArray)) {
        foreach ($requestArray as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach($v as $v2) {
                    $request .= urlencode($k).'[]='.urlencode($v2).'&';
                }
            }
            else {
                $request .= urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v).'&';
            }
        }
        $request = substr($request,0,-1);
    }
    $data = "POST ".$url['path'].((!empty($url['query'])) ? '?'.$url['query'] : '')." HTTP/1.0\r\n"
    ."Host: ".$url['host']."\r\n"
    ."Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    ."User-Agent: PHP\r\n"
    ."Content-length: ".strlen($request)."\r\n"
    ."Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
    .$request."\r\n\r\n";
    socket_send($sock, $data, strlen($data), 0);

    $result = '';
    do {
        $piece = socket_read($sock, 1024);
        $result .= $piece;
    }
    while($piece != '');
    socket_close($sock);
    // TODO: Add Header Validation for 404, 403, 401, 500 etc.
    echo $result;
```

Of course you have to change it to fill your needs or wrap it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if you have PHP configured with pecl_http is:

`$response = http_post_data($url, $post_params_string);`

The function is documented on php.net:

- Documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php
- Install: http://php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

PECL also provides a well documented way to handle Cookies, Redirects, Authentication etc before the POST:

http://php.net/manual/en/http.request.options.php

Answer (score -1):

RESTclient is a nice little app for this: http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/