# Send GET request without CURL

Tags: php, http, get

I'm trying to send GET request without CURL but with Header.
What is the problem?

Here is code of my bla bla bla bla bla bla bla:

```
private function getRequest($url, $data){
    $uri = $this->api_url . $url;
    $content = http_build_query($data);
    $content = urldecode($content); 

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 
                            "Authorization : Bearer " . $this->access_token . "\r\n",
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'content' => $content,//$data = ['key' => 'value']
        ),
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    var_dump($context); //resource(70) of type (stream-context) 
    if (fopen($uri, 'r', false, $context)) //NO
        echo "yes";
    else  
        echo "no";
    fpassthru($fp); //empty

}
```

Here is $options return value:

```
    Array
(
    [http] => Array
        (
            [header] => Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization : Bearer kEQn2I02JOegz6gD4

            [method] => GET
            [content] => address=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0 //cyrillic, with ENG doesn't work anyway
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596311/how-to-make-a-post-request-without-curl

Comment: @JavaBoy `file_get_contents` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have space in headers after "Authorization", try this one:

```
private function getRequest($url, $data){
    $uri = $this->api_url . $url; 

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 
                         "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->access_token . "\r\n",
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),//$data = ['key' => 'value']
        ),
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    var_dump($context); //resource(70) of type (stream-context) 
    if (fopen($uri, 'r', false, $context)) //NO
        echo "yes";
    else  
        echo "no";
    fpassthru($fp); //empty

}
```

Comment: I've tested it on my local server and have got an error `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` and `no` response. When i've deleted the space in header the result was `yes` and no errors. Could you enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to E_ALL? May be PHP generates some error that would be helpful

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(http://site/api/route/stops): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/*****api.php on line 73`

Comment: Do you know what this error means or you assume the problem is deeper?

Comment: It means that I cannot use `fopen()` or `file_get_contents()` on remote server... Instead of I need to use cURL

Comment: This error means that server (site) couldn't find what you requested (http://site/api/route/stops). It's the problem of http://site, not `file_get_contents` or `stream_context_create`

Comment: Yeah, I think  `allow_url_fopen` in php.ini is the problem, but I can't change it. So, I rewrote it using cURL