# Send a complete custom HTTP request message to a server in PHP over HTTPS

Tags: php, http

Is it possible to send a fully custom HTTP message to a server that I have stored in the HTTP code in a string in PHP?

In other words, I've completely crafted the HTTP request and just want to forward that message without having cURL or another library "build" the message for me using parameters and overriding things like URLs etc. I'm concerned curl won't send it to the server I want it to and use the *URL* for the domain.

This is for a test suite to test Host header injection to ensure our server code continues to rejects such attempts over the coarse of its lifetime.

```php
$httpMessage = join("\r\n", [
    "POST https://www.malicious-domain.com/my/uri/path HTTP/1.1",
        // Laravel can be tricked into poisoning its own caches
        // with other domains without the correct interventions
    "Host: localhost.dev",
    "Accept: application/json",
    // ...
]);;

// Send this custom HTTP request message over HTTPS
// to my local dev server https://localhost.dev and receive a response
// In the same way that BurpSuite can
$response = ...
```

Comment: If you tell curl the url to send the request to, it'll send it there. I'm not sure what your concern is on that point. But anyway if you want to just send a raw http request try opening a simple socket. Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8596359/5947043

Comment: You'll need to use `fsockopen()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: `fsockopen` worked, thank you.